# Issue install Parity on ARM64 with Docker (NVIDIA Xavier Jetson)

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, ethereum, nvidia-jetson

I'm trying to install Parity on my NVIDIA Xavier Jetson, but keep getting stuck.

I'm following the instructions here: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-snappy/wiki/Docker-build-for-ARM-ARM64

However I keep getting an error message:

> standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format
>   error"

The full error message is below, however the above error code has happened with a few different install method attempts (inc. snapcraft).

> Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.468MB Step 1/10 : FROM
>   ubuntu:14.04.5  ---> 132b7427a3b4 Step 2/10 : WORKDIR /build  --->
>   Using cache  ---> e3ab6318dc67 Step 3/10 : RUN apt-get -y update &&
>   apt-get install -y --force-yes --no-install-recommends         curl
>   git make g++ gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu g++-aarch64-linux-gnu
>   libc6-arm64-cross libc6-dev-arm64-cross wget file ca-certificates
>   binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu         &&     apt-get clean  ---> Running
>   in b12bf8ce43fd standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused
>   "exec format error" The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update &&
>   apt-get install -y --force-yes --no-install-recommends         curl
>   git make g++ gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu g++-aarch64-linux-gnu
>   libc6-arm64-cross libc6-dev-arm64-cross wget file ca-certificates
>   binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu         &&     apt-get clean' returned a
>   non-zero code: 1

I am running Docker for linux/arm64 on Ubuntu 18.04 (install with Jetapack 4.1). For the life of me I just can't figure this out.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `linux/arm64` - and what is your host architecture? Can you post `uname -a`?

Comment: host arch is: Linux jetson-0423318029408 4.9.108-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 31 15:17:21 PDT 2018 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Comment: This `exec user process caused "exec format error"` looks like the executable format does not match the format of your machine. I would get the same error if I would execute aarch64 executable on x86_64 machine. As far as i know, arm64 and aarch64 is the same thing. But it's strange you install packages with aarch64 and arm64. Also, doesn't the log output you provided differ from the [dockerfile](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-snappy/blob/master/Dockerfile)?

Comment: Good pickup @KamilCuk. Its weird the Dockerfile in the link I provide is different from the version you found. I tried your version and it didn't error at execution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@kamil_cuk answered the question in the comments. The Dockerfile I was using was an old version. Latest version is here: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-snappy/blob/master/Dockerfile